# How to retrieve child records from database using Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two tables, a `map_families` table and a `map_contacts` table. There is a one to many relationship between these two tables and when a Family record is displayed I'd like to display any child records it has from the `map_contacts` table.

At the moment though, I have this code:

```
        $familylist = $dm->createQuery('
        SELECT mf.id, mf.surname, mf.firstName, mf.email, mf.phone, mc.id AS memID, mc.firstName AS memFirstName, mc.surname AS memSurname
        FROM MyBundle:MapFamilies mf
        LEFT JOIN MyBundle:MapContacts mc WHERE mf.id = mc.family
        WHERE mf.centre = :centre
        ORDER BY mf.surname ASC, mf.firstName ASC'
        )->setParameter('centre', $centre);

        $famlist = $familylist->getResult();
```

And this gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [surname] => Kentucky
            [firstName] => John
            [email] => email@somewhere.com
            [phone] => 0123 456 7890
            [memID] => 2
            [memFirstName] => Jason
            [memSurname] => Kentucky
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [surname] => Kentucky
            [firstName] => John
            [email] => email@somewhere.com
            [phone] => 0123 456 7890
            [memID] => 3
            [memFirstName] => Michael
            [memSurname] => Kentucky
        )

)
```

But what I'm trying to get is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [surname] => Kentucky
            [firstName] => John
            [email] => email@somewhere.com
            [phone] => 0123 456 7890
            [members] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                    [memID] => 2
                    [memFirstName] => Mick
                    [memSurname] => Burke
                  ),
              [1] => Array
                  (
                    [memID] => 3
                    [memFirstName] => John
                    [memSurname] => Burke
                  )
            )

        )
)
```

How can I do this through Symfony2?

Comment: Have you considered using Doctrine 2's ORM functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're after in querybuilder.

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $result = $qb->select('mf, mc')
        ->from('MyBundle:MapFamilies', 'mf')
        ->join('mf.mapContacts', 'mc')
        ->where('mf.centre = :centre')
        ->setParameter('centre', $centre)
        ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

This will give you an array of MapFamily, with their relevant MapContact entities.

I took a guess at your property name for MapFamily -> MapContact so you might need to change that.